# Compare DateTime in EF Core Linq Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I am using .NETCore and EF Core in my project. I am unable to query items with expressions using DateTimes.

```
return _context.table
       .Where( x=> x.CPULoad > 90 && X.Date >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5));
```

The CPULoad works perfect but the datetime comparions outputs the below.

```
The LINQ expression '(([x].Date >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5))' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try this...

```
var compareDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5);
return _context.table
    .Where( x=> x.CPULoad > 90 && X.Date >= compareDate);
```

essentially the problem here is entity framework does not know how to convert `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5)` to SQL, so you need to get the value and then pass that to entity framework.

Comment: Thank you! i think im getting closer... I now see teh query in my output but my result are still "everything". In my output i see this
```
Executed DbCommand [Parameters=[@__date_0='?'].......] <left out rest for breveity>

SELECT [x]/[id], [x]...
FROM ...
Where [x].Date >= @__date_0 AND ...
```

Comment: Hard to say what is going on here now without more context... What does the model for `table` look like?  You can also try to run the generated EF query directly in SSMS and try and debug it from there.

Comment: The model has the property 'Date' which is a type of 'DateTime'. i tried to make sure those matched.